# How do I know I'm running within "go test"

Tags: unit-testing, go

When I run "go test", I want to use a different configuration file. How do I know within my code if I'm running within a test context or a normal context? Is there some sort of environment variable to check?

Comment: Did you ever figure out a good solution to this? I'm dealing with the exact same problems with almost the exact same config setup as you.

Comment: @Cody There might be a "good solution", currently being implemented, [for Go 1.22 (Q3 2023)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75787351/6309).

Answer (score 59):

The testing package modifies the global environment when loaded: it registers a lot of command-line flags. So, we can check if these flags are registered:

```
func init() {
    if flag.Lookup("test.v") == nil {
        fmt.Println("normal run")
    } else {
        fmt.Println("run under go test")
    }
}
```

Comment: It is important to note that if you import testing in any non *_test.go file this approach will not work. It will always assume the test run. I ran into this when I added some utility functions that allowed a testing.T to be passed for failures.

Comment: Experimentally, this answer seems correct. It's important to understand that we want to simply test for the presence/absence of the flag (flag.Lookup("test.v") == nil), which indicates that the testing framework has registered the flag. Furthermore, we don't care about the actual value of the flag if it's present (checking from init(), there's a good chance it's not even been parsed yet).

Comment: This worked fine for me!! Thanks

Comment: This doesn't work anymore on the more recent versions of Go.

Comment: @Kedare I'm running 1.19.4 and it's working as described above.

Answer (score 42):

Since the `flag.Lookup("test.v")` approach does not work for me, I'd like to share my own solution:

```
strings.HasSuffix(os.Args[0], ".test")
```

Or

```
strings.Contains(os.Args[0], "/_test/")
```

Both seem to work.

Comment: The `flag.Lookup("test.v")` approach used to work, now it doesn't (I'm using 1.8.1).

Comment: `strings.HasSuffix(os.Args[0], ".test")` is more reliable for me.  There is one development machine where `strings.Contains(os.Args[0], "/_test/")` failed.

Comment: This worked for me while the `flag.Lookup("test.v")` did not. In fact, when I looked at the `flag.formal` map (which is what is indexed by `flag.Lookup`), there were no flags at all.

Comment: That will not work if your test runner called its binary without a `.test` extension using the `-o` flag. FWIW the `flag.Lookup("test.v")` method appears to work in 1.18.

Comment: Normally the ideal is to use `TestMain`. However, **this approach helped me for preparing/setting-up `Example*_*` functions** in the test. It was useful to simplify the example and focus on showing how to use the functions/methods. Without using extra code like mocking just for the examples.

Answer (score 14):

> How do I know within my code if I'm running within a test context or a normal context?

Go 1.22 (Q3 2023) or Go 1.23 (Q1 2024) could provide this feature, considering the proposal "[# 5600 testing: add `func Testing() bool`](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/52600)" has been accepted, and is currently implemented.
See [CL 475496](https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/go/+/475496):

> ### testing: add `Testing` function
>
> The Testing function reports whether the program is a test created by "`go test`".

With [`src/testing/testing.go`](https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/go/+/475496/3/src/testing/testing.go)

```golang
// testBinary is set by cmd/go to "1" if this is a binary built by "go test".
// The value is set to "1" by a -X option to cmd/link. We assume that
// because this is possible, the compiler will not optimize testBinary
// into a constant on the basis that it is an unexported package-scope
// variable that is never changed. If the compiler ever starts implementing
// such an optimization, we will need some technique to mark this variable
// as "changed by a cmd/link -X option".
var testBinary = "0"

// Testing reports whether the current code is being run in a test.
// This will report true in programs created by "go test",
// false in programs created by "go build".
func Testing() bool {
    return testBinary == "1"
}
```

[Example](https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/go/+/475496/3/src/testing/testing_test.go):

```golang
package main
import (
    "fmt"
    "testing"
)
func main() {
    fmt.Println(testing.Testing())
}

func TestTesting(t *testing.T) {
    if !testing.Testing() {
        t.Errorf("testing.Testing() == %t, want %t", testing.Testing(), true)
    }
}
```

[Use case example](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/52600#issuecomment-1423816571):

> With `testing.Testing()` I can easily guard non-unit-tests code with:
>
> ```golang
> // file/that/should/not/be/used/from/testing.go
>
> func prodEnvironmentData() *Environment {
>    if testing.Testing() {
>        log.Fatal("Using production data in unit tests")
>    }
>    ....
> }
> ```

---

> Do you know what downsides does it have to import "testing" on "production code"?

Importing the `testing` package in production code is generally discouraged and can have several downsides. The `testing` package is intended for use in test files, not in production code. Its design and utilities are optimized for writing and running tests. Using it in production code blurs the line between test and production environments, leading to potential confusion and maintainability issues.

Importing additional packages, including `testing`, can increase the size of the final binary.
Although modern compilers are efficient at optimizing unused code paths, introducing logic checks like `if testing.Testing() {...}` could potentially lead to unnecessary overhead. That is especially true if these checks are placed in performance-critical paths of the application.
Exposing the fact that certain code paths are intended for testing could provide hints to malicious actors about how to trigger unexpected behavior in your application, especially if those paths are inadequately protected or expose sensitive testing functionality.

And you have alternatives:

- Using environment variables or a dedicated configuration management system can be a more appropriate way to alter behavior between production and test environments without introducing test-specific dependencies into your production code.
- [Go's build tag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67946874/6309) system allows you to include or exclude files from the build process based on specific tags. You could use this feature to isolate test-specific functionality without importing the `testing` package into your production codebase.
- For cases where different behaviors are needed between production and test environments, consider using interfaces and dependency injection. That approach allows you to mock dependencies in your tests without changing the production code's behavior.

Comment: I want to discuss about something. Do you know what downsides does it have to import "testing" on "production code"? If you know that's ok, if not I would like to read other people's opinions.

Answer (score 11):

The `flag.Lookup("test.v") == nil` method seems to work but I would recommend using [TestMain](https://golang.org/pkg/testing/#hdr-Main), which is specifically designed to allow specific setup and teardown for tests. If you include this method in the package you want to test, it will be called before your individual tests and so you can set a global flag or perform whatever test-specific configuration you want to do before calling m.Run() as follows

```
func TestMain(m *testing.M) {
    // test context initialization here
    os.Exit(m.Run())
}
```

PS: this is actually what @calvin-sugianto suggested, except Gin has nothing to do with it

Comment: This appears to be the best answer as it is documented on golang.org and will continue to be supported. The answers based on undocumented flags should be avoided imo.

Comment: This is a great point, but has the issue of not being called before init(), so cannot be used to control actions of init()

Comment: @AndrewPrice Would you be so kind as to provide a link to where this is documented on golang.org?

Comment: @0p3r4t0r here it is: https://pkg.go.dev/testing#hdr-Main

Answer (score 9):

One possibility would be to use [build constraints](http://golang.org/pkg/go/build/#hdr-Build_Constraints).  If you run `go test` as:

```
go test -tags testing pkgname
```

Then you can use that tag to select which files will be included in a standard build of your package, and which will be used for testing.

If you put your standard configuration in a file of its own, then adding a line to the top like the following will ensure that it is not used for testing:

```
// +build !testing
```

You can then include the testing configuration in one of the `*_test.go` files, or in some other file that requires that the `testing` tag be set.

Comment: Ideally, there shouldn't be any sort of magic word necessary to indicate that the code is running within a unit-testing context. "go test" should set _something_ that indicates this is unit-testing.

Comment: no it shouldn't. You are right that there shouldn't be a magic word necessary to indicate the is running within a unit-testing context. not from go test and not from you. Your tests should have a *different* function setting up the test enviroment which your test files then call explicitly

Comment: The problem with having "different function setting" is that it relies on the ernest effort of engineers.  If my framework needs to swap out mock testing bits during my framework users' tests, I want to do it automatically under my control as a framework designer.  Note that this does not preclude the ability for tests to craft refinements in the behavior of my framework during testing. But it does rely on my ability to known when I'm running in a test environment.

Answer (score 8):

Code examples would help. But from your question it sounds like you've hardcoded a path to a config file somewhere when you probably wanted to pass it in instead.

Change the function you are testing to take a parameter defining the config file and then in your test code pass a different path in than you use in the non test code. It's bad practice for your code to have a different path when testing vs production.

Comment: I don't have hard-coded paths. I have different configuration files for each environment (dev, beta, prod, etc). I want a "unit-testing" environment that is used whenever "go test" is run. Right now, I'm having to do "ENV=test go test ./..." and that's janky. I was hoping there would be something that I can test that "go test" sets itself.

Comment: Then have your test functions use the dev config file as part of their setup. This should not be determined from code that will run in production. That's asking for all kinds of trouble.

Comment: I agree with Jeremy. The path to configuration should not be detected accorig whether run test or not. That code smells. You should explicitely write a path - one in function main, second in your test function. Do not hide your dependency.

Answer (score 5):

I am new to golang and `flag.Lookup("test.v")` did not work for me, So i have found way to identify if context is testing or normal by setting ENV variable in init().

If you have test file for example abc.text.go, set env variable "GO_ENV" to testing in init().

```
func init() {
    os.Setenv("GO_ENV", "testing")
}
```

And where ever you want to know the context use os.Getenv("GO_ENV")
abc.go

```
if os.Getenv("GO_ENV") == "testing" {

} else {

}
```

Answer (score 3):

The `flag.Lookup("test.v")` solution does not work for me either (go 1.13), and I have lots of services to maintain and it is not feasible to use the `func TestMain(m *testing.M)` solution in every service. As all the services share a common library, I've come up with the following solution:

```
func isInTests() bool {
    for _, arg := range os.Args {
        if strings.HasPrefix(arg, "-test.v=") {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

This is similar to the `flag.Lookup("test.v")` solution because we check if `-test.v` is present.

**EDIT**: updated the code based on @mh-cbon comment

Comment: I would do `if strings.HasPrefix(arg, "-test.") {`. Your code won't catch running test is the -v flag is set to false.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Pram's answer I might set an environment variable when you run the tests.

Makefile

```
test:
 ENV=testing go test ./...
```

main.go

```
  env := os.Getenv("ENV")
```

Answer (score 0):

If your trying to detect if the file is being run through "go run" vs an executable, this function checks if the directory contains "/Temp/go-build" (also checks for \ for windows support)

```
if strings.Index(os.Args[0], "/Temp/go-build") != -1 || strings.Index(os.Args[0], "\\Temp\\go-build") != -1 {
    // ran with go run
} else {
    // ran as executable file
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**A different approach will be using a seperate init() func in test file per package.**

Since *_test.go runs only during 'go test' we could

*feature/feature_setup_test.go*

```
package feature

fun init() {  
       fmt.Println("Code For Test initialization")
}
```

This init() func from test is called only during testing; **Unlike an init() func from *feature.go* which will with every import/run**.

And one more thing when we do testing, init() in test will get executed only after non-test init() function.

**So you can override the a *feature.go -> init()* with *feature_test.go -> init()*.**

[Sample code available in gist.](https://gist.github.com/var23rav/fd28c24d83b275eb79fbc00808c3358e)

Answer (score 0):

Check if `_test.go` exist in stack.

```golang
package utils

import (
    "runtime/debug"
    "strings"
)

func IsInTest() bool {
    stacks := strings.Split(string(debug.Stack()), "\n")
    for _, line := range stacks {
        if strings.HasPrefix(line, "\t") {
            path := strings.Split(strings.TrimSpace(line), ":")[0]
            if strings.HasSuffix(path, "_test.go") {
                return true
            }
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

More robust solution that Garrett's one is:

```
 func init() {
    if v := flag.Lookup("test.v"); v == nil || v.Value.String() != "true" {
        fmt.Println("normal run")
    } else {
        fmt.Println("run under go test")
    }
 }
```

Comment: It's not Garrett's, it's my answer. And we don't need to know value of this flag, all we need to know is package "test" was loaded and thus has registered this flag.

Comment: I am seeing this usage in the wild and want to re-iterate the comment by @Powerman that it is *incorrect*. Testing the value for true/false is effectively testing to see that the verbose testing flag was given, which is irrelevant. Furthermore, if used in init(), it's likely that flag.Parse() has not yet been called, so the value cannot be used. It's sufficient to check that flag.Lookup("test.v") != nil to detect the testing framework.