# How to properly use build tags?

Tags: go, build, go-build

I need to be able to build different versions of a go application; a 'debug' version and a normal version.

This is easy to do; I simply have a const DEBUG, that controls the behaviour of the application, but it's annoying to have to edit the config file every time I need to swap between build types.

I was reading about go build (http://golang.org/pkg/go/build/) and tags, I thought perhaps I could do this:

config.go:

```
// +build !debug
package build
const DEBUG = false
```

config.debug.go:

```
// +build debug
package build
const DEBUG = true
```

Then I should be able to build using `go build` or `go build -tags debug`, and the tags should exclude `config.go` and include `config.debug.go`.

...but this doesn't work. I get:

> src/build/config.go:3: DEBUG redeclared in this block (<0>) previous
> declaration at src/build/config.debug.go:3

What am I doing wrong?

Is there another and more appropriate #ifdef style way of doing this I should be using?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

See [my answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10646531/golang-conditional-compilation/10649653#10649653). You need a blank line after the `// +build` line.

Also, you probably want the `!` in config.go, not in config.debug.go; and presumably you want one to be "DEBUG = false".

Comment: See @blackgreen's answer for Go 1.17+: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67946874/102699

Answer (score 22):

You could use compile time constants for that: If you compile your program with

```
go build -ldflags '-X main.DEBUG=YES' test.go
```

the variable `DEBUG` from package main will be set to the string "YES". Otherwise it keeps its declared contents.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

var DEBUG = "NO"

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("DEBUG is %q\n", DEBUG)
}
```

---

Edit: since Go 1.6(?) the switch is `-X main.DEBUG=YES`, before that it was `-X main.DEBUG YES` (without the `=`). Thanks to a comment from @poorva.

Comment: Is this possible for non-string data?

Comment: @MattJoiner didn't test everything but it is possible with ints.

Answer (score 4):

As of Go 1.17, build tags can be specified with the new [`//go:build`](https://golang.org/design/draft-gobuild) syntax.

As for the placement of the `//go:build` directive, the new design states:

> Constraints may appear in any kind of source file (not just Go), but they must appear near the top of the file, preceded only by blank lines and other `//` and `/* */` comments. These rules mean that in Go files a build constraint must appear before the package clause.

So you still need to leave a blank line between the `//go:build` directive and the package statement, otherwise it could be parsed as package documentation, however now:

- the compiler will reject misplaced directives
- running `go fmt` will automatically fix misplaced directives

For example running `go fmt` on (no blank line):

```
//go:build foo
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello world")
}
```

gives (with blank line):

```
//go:build foo

package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello world")
}
```

---

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67937234/4108803) for further details about what changes with the new syntax.