# How to set build tags in source file

Tags: go, build

New to go. I'm familiar with the ability to consume build tags in source files like so:

```
// +build linux arm,!linux
```

but is there any way to create/export build tags in a source file? Something like:

```
// +build +custom_tag_name
```

I'm trying to do what the -tags argument does inside of a source file instead of adding it to a makefile so that when a library is added to a project, it will "set" certain tags that can be used in other files.

Comment: `// +build custom_tag_name` will work just fine. Have you actually tried it and run into some issue?

Comment: My understanding is that using // +build custom_tag would consume the tag, not create a new tag that could be consumed in other files. If // +build custom_tag created tags, then using build tags to resolve correct source files wouldn't work.

Comment: This question shows an example of "consuming" build tags in a source file: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15214459/how-to-properly-use-build-tags

In that example, the tags are "created"/"set" with the -tags debug flag on the cli.

Comment: Tags are not "created", they're just arbitrary text. As the documentation states, files will be compiled at build time so long as their build constraints (if any) are satisfied. Constraints can be set by file name convention or by comments. Some constraints are satisfied implicitly by the environment (GOOS, GOARCH, Go version, etc), others are satisfied explicitly by passing a `-tags` parameter. It's not clear what you're trying to do here or what isn't working.

Comment: You can't do that. Source files can only set build constraints on themselves, they can't satisfy constraints. Constraints can only be satisfied as noted - implicitly by the environment, or explicitly via the `-tags` flag.

Comment: You should make that the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that. Source files can only set build constraints on themselves, they can't satisfy constraints. Constraints can only be satisfied as noted - implicitly by the environment, or explicitly via the -tags flag. Build constraints are a way to achieve environment-sensitive conditional compilation. Using one source file to control the build of another doesn't really make sense; you know at build time whether file A is in the build, so you know whether file B should be in the build. This seems like an XY Problem, possibly better solved by a mechanism similar to that of the SQL drivers (registering a handler in an `init` function) or something like that?